# Mono for Android how to show dialog/popUpWindow on front of another application

Tags: c#, android, mono

I'm trying to show a dialog/popUpWindow on top of the active application.
I have an activity which starts an application via intents. I want to show the dialog just after my activity goes to background and the called application comes to foreground.

In the OnStop() method of my activity I have the following code:

```
var dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.SetContentView(Resource.Layout.childLayout);
dialog.SetTitle("PopUp");
dialog.SetCancelable(true);
dialog.Show();
```

but the dialog doesn't appear on top of the current application (started from my activity), it appears behind it and in front of my activity.

How can I bring the dialog/popUpWindow on top of the current window/application?

This is the code which launches the 2 intents: first intents launches adobe reader and second intent launches my transparent activity:

```
var intentPdf = new Intent();
PackageManager pm = PackageManager;    
intentPdf = pm.GetLaunchIntentForPackage("com.adobe.reader");
intentPdf.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
StartActivity(intentPdf);

Thread.Sleep(5000);

var showChildActivity = new Intent();
showChildActivity.SetClass(this, typeof(ChildActivity));
showChildActivity.SetAction(Intent.ActionMain);
showChildActivity.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront);
StartActivity(showChildActivity);
```

Answer (score 1):

You created a dialog and it will be in front of your activity.Its natural behavior for android.So what you need to do is after starting application via intent you need to fire another intent to start another activity of yours.This activity will be transparent and will have a diloag in onCreate.

Comment: I tried your solution but I have 2 issues: the window of the  second activity is black (not transparent), and the activity, although in code is started after the third party application via an intent, is not brought to the front of the screen.

Comment: I solved the transparency problem but it remains the second problem: my transparent activity is not in the foreground although it's intent is started after the adobe reader intent. I posted the code in my question.

Comment: I removed Thread.sleep but I get the same result: my transparent activity is somehow in the background because if I close Adobe Reader, than the pop dialog from my transparent activity is shown. I can't bring my activity on top of Adobe Reader.

Comment: thats weired, try by simply writing startActivity(this,ChildActivity.class);

Comment: I can't try startActivity(this,ChildActivity.class) because I'm in Mono but I tried startActivity(typeof(ChildActivity)) and I get the same behavior :(.

Comment: ok.just to check.can you replace pdf activity by any other android activity to see the behaviour.

Comment: I tried another pdf viewer and now the behavior is right, my activity is on top of the reader. Then I tried to open the browser and it's the behavior as with adobe reader, my activity is in the background.